# Obtener información de introspección para miembros de clase

Tags: python, python-3.x

Para ir aprendiendo, estoy intentando hacer un *volcador* de los componentes de un determinado módulo. El objetivo es usarlo para obtener información sobre el contenido de los módulos accesibles mediate el *GObjectIntrospection* de las librerías `GLib`/`Gtk`:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import inspect
import importlib

class dummy:
  def __init__( self ):
    super( dummy, self ).__init__( self )

def dumpFunction( label, item ):
  try:
    sign = inspect.signature( item )
  except ValueError:
    print( label, '=>', 'function( ? )' )
    return

  notFirst = 0

  print( label, '=> function( ', end = '' )
  for k, v in sign.parameters.items( ):
    if notFirst:
      print( ', ', end = '' )

    print( v.name, end = '' )
    if v.default != inspect.Parameter.empty:
      print( ' =', v.default, end = '' )
    notFirst = 1
  print( ' )' )

  if sign.return_annotation != inspect.Signature.empty:
    print( ' -> ', sign.return_annotation )

  sys.stdout.flush( )

def dumpModule( item ):
  funcType = type( dumpModule )
  funcInternal = type( print )
  classType = type( dummy )

  for v in dir( item ):
    if v.startswith( '_' ):
      continue

    attr = getattr( item, v )
    attrType = type( attr )

    if ( attrType == funcType ) or ( attrType == funcInternal ):
      dumpFunction( v, attr )
    elif( attrType == classType ):
      print( v, '=> class {' )
      dumpModule( attr )
      print( '}' )
    else:
      print( v, '=>', attrType )

if len( sys.argv ) == 2:
  if sys.argv[1].startswith( 'gi.' ):
    print( 'PENDIENTE' )
  else:
    todump = importlib.import_module( sys.argv[1] )
    dumpModule( todump )
else:
  print( 'Usage: dumpmodule NOMBRE_MODULO' )
```

Eso es solo el *boceto* preliminar, faltan aún cosillas por hacer; pero funcionar, funciona:

```
./prueba os
```

> EX_CANTCREAT => <class 'int'>
>   EX_CONFIG => <class 'int'>
>   EX_DATAERR => <class 'int'>
>   EX_IOERR => <class 'int'>
>   EX_NOHOST => <class 'int'>
>   EX_NOINPUT => <class 'int'>
>   EX_NOPERM => <class 'int'>
>   EX_NOUSER => <class 'int'>
>   EX_OK => <class 'int'>
>   ...

Se supone que debe mostar información sobre las funciones existentes en el módulo, y también lo hace correctamente:

> access => function( path, mode, dir_fd = None, effective_ids = False, follow_symlinks = True )
>   chdir => function( path )
>   chmod => function( path, mode, dir_fd = None, follow_symlinks = True )
>   chown => function( path, uid, gid, dir_fd = None, follow_symlinks = True )

Igualmente, debe de funcionar para clases, y tambien parece que funciona ... **en parte**:

> error => class {
>   args => <class 'getset_descriptor'>
>   characters_written => <class 'getset_descriptor'>
>   errno => <class 'member_descriptor'>
>   filename => <class 'member_descriptor'>
>   filename2 => <class 'member_descriptor'>
>   strerror => &ltclass 'member_descriptor'>
>   with_traceback => <class 'method_descriptor'>
>   }

Parece ser que las funciones y las variables miembros de clase, son manejados de una forma especial, y las funciones `type( )` y `inspect.signature( )` no ofrecen los resultados esperados. Y no encuentro nada relevante en [la documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).

¿ Cómo obtengo información de introspección sobre esos miembros de clases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase `error` que estás tratando de inspeccionar no está definida en realidad en el módulo `os`, sino que está definida en el módulo `posix` y es importada al espacio de nombres de  `os` cuando éste se carga.

El problema es que el módulo `posix` es un *builtin*, su código fuente está en C en lugar de python, y sobre él los poderes de introspección están muy menguados.

Muchos de los *builtins* de python no pueden informar de su signature, por ejemplo:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.isbuiltin(print)
True
>>> inspect.signature(print)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jldiaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 2987, in signature
    return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
  File "/home/jldiaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 2737, in from_callable
    follow_wrapper_chains=follow_wrapped)
  File "/home/jldiaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 2230, in _signature_from_callable
    skip_bound_arg=skip_bound_arg)
  File "/home/jldiaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 2060, in _signature_from_builtin
    raise ValueError("no signature found for builtin {!r}".format(func))
ValueError: no signature found for builtin <built-in function print>
```

Algunos en cambio sí, depende de cómo hayan sido implementados:

```
>>> inspect.isbuiltin(open)
True
>>> inspect.signature(open)
<Signature (file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)>
```

Los métodos de una clase que te aparecen como `method_descriptor` no tienen capacidad de introspección.

Ya que tu objetivo último es usarlo para inspeccionar Gtk, y ésta está programada mayormente en C++, me temo que encontrarás esta barrera a menudo.

Comment: Con la *ilu* que me hacía ... Pues valla *chasco* :-(